# Флаг immediate или замена rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq

Привет.
Мне необходимо отправлять сообщения с полным подтверждением доставки - сообщение было отправлено в нужную очередь и было взято на выполнение.
Дело в том, что задача, которая будет выполнена позже, даже на 5-10 секунд уже не имеет никакого значения.

Соответственно мне необходимо использовать два флага mandatory и immediate.
Оказалось, что флаг immediate не поддерживается в rabbitmq с версии 3.0. Вместо этого разработчики предлагают использовать TTL=0 для очереди.
С оговоркой, что ждать подтверждение, о том что сообщение было брошено на пол, не следует.

Такое поведение мне совсем не подходит.

Есть ли какая-нибудь возможность мониторить не взятые в обработку сообщения? Поделитесь опытом как вы решали похожие задачи.
В целом rabbitmq полностью покрывает весь спектр задач необходимых мне, но пока дело в выборе инструмента готов заменить его на аналоги с такой же функциональностью.

---

Попробую подробнее описать задачу.
У меня есть клиенты, которые ходят в ручки API.

API в свою очередь отправляет сообщение в rabbitmq. Rabbit - воркерам.
В будущем будет некий heartbeat в виде базы данных, который будет хранить состояние выполняемых задач воркерами.

Клиенту я должен ответить сразу, что что-то пошло не так. Соответственно, он, обработав ошибку, мог повторить запрос - это требование.
Количество воркеров я могу увеличивать до определенного предела, чтобы не упереться в железку. 
Расположить воркеров на других серверах тоже не могу - и тоже это требование (выполнение завязано именно на определенный сервер).

Comment: У меня такое ощущение, что вы пытаетесь реализовать синхронную обработку через очередь. Если вам настолько критично получить ответ, проще это сделать внутренними HTTP-запросами, которые вам сразу скажут состояние.